# What was the Lycan cannon?

Tags: underworld, underworld-blood-wars

In Blood Wars, the Lycan Horde under Marius had a weapon that basically turned the tide of the siege of the Eastern Coven. It fired a fairly luminescent round.  What was this weapon and what is the history behind it, in and out of universe?